# section listview and overflow imageview on section

Tags: android, listview

i use [pinned section list view](https://github.com/beworker/pinned-section-listview) library and add imageView on left section such that imageView is overflow from section and it is perch on above items

how can i create this layout?

thanks.

like this **[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T222m.png)**